# Setting zoom level on clicking a button

Tags: jquery

I have this script that is changing the zoom level. At the moment, if you keep clicking the buttons the size will just get bigger/smaller.

Is there a way I can adjust so that when you click the small button it sets the zoom to a specific level and doesn't allow for multiple presses? Ditto for the large button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    var currFFZoom = 1;
    var currIEZoom = 100;

    $('#large').on('click',function(){
        if ($.browser.mozilla){
            var step = 0.02;
            currFFZoom += step; 
            $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
        } else {
            var step = 15;
            currIEZoom += step;
            $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
        }
    });

    $('#small').on('click',function(){
        if ($.browser.mozilla){
            var step = 0.02;
            currFFZoom -= step;                 
            $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');

        } else {
            var step = 2;
            currIEZoom -= step;
            $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
        }
    });

    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/), it attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

Change you code as

```
$('#small').one('click',function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of .on()

```
$('#large').one('click',function(){
```

From Documentation, *The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.*